# Changing image source on mouseover/mouseout in React/Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, styled-components

**Technologies I use:**

Next.js
Styled-Components
Typescript

**What I want to do:**

I wish to change image to a different one when I hover over the parent div that wraps it (Card).

**What is my solution:**

I managed to do that with use of useState like so:

```
const [isHovering, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
const [isHovering2, setIsHovered2] = useState(false);
const [isHovering3, setIsHovered3] = useState(false);


  

      <Card1>
        <Card
          onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
        >
          <IconWrapper>
            {isHovering ? (
              <Image layout="fill" src={image1OnHover} />
            ) : (
              <Image layout="fill" src={image1} />
            )}
          </IconWrapper>
          <CardText>
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>
              Dorem Ipsum.
            </p>
          </CardText>
        </Card>
      </Card1>

      <Card2>
        <Card
          onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered2(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered2(false)}
        >
          <IconWrapper>
            {isHovering2 ? (
              <Image layout="fill" src={image2OnHover} />
            ) : (
              <Image layout="fill" src={image2} />
            )}
          </IconWrapper>
          <CardText>
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>
              Dorem Ipsum
            </p>
          </CardText>
        </Card>
      </Card2>

      <Card3>
        <Card
          onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered3(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered3(false)}
        >
          <IconWrapper>
            {isHovering3 ? (
              <Image layout="fill" src={image3OnHover} />
            ) : (
              <Image layout="fill" src={image3} />
            )}
          </IconWrapper>
          <CardText>
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>
              Dorem Ipsum
            </p>
          </CardText>
        </Card>
```

**What I'd like to ask for:**

It seems to me like this code looks awful and is not really following the DRY principle.

It works but I don't think that spamming useStates is a good idea (what if there were 100 images to change... that would be pain to write).

I've been searching web for some better ideas, but I only found examples similar to what I've coded and for singular images.
The problem here is that if I was to only use one state, then all of the images would change at the same time - which forces me to use individual hooks for each and every element I add to the page.

This is my first ever request on stackoverflow - I apologize if my post is not up to standards - hopefully it'll do ;)

Comment: How do the components `Card1`, `Card2` and `Card3` differ from each other?

Comment: These are styled components, each of cards has different positioning, that's why they are all numbered. Other than that, everything is pretty much the same (Except ofcoz different images). 
Not sure if that answers your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another Option is to make a component that handles the state itself then pass the two image options into it. Here is an example of a simple component that does that: https://codesandbox.io/s/hoverimage-ldscek?file=/src/OnHoverImage.js:40-449. Then you could map that component and display that component as many times as you like easily.

```
export const OnHoverImage = ({ hoveredImage, image, alt }) => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px" }}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
    >
      {hover ? (
        <img src={image} alt={alt} />
      ) : (
        <img src={hoveredImage} alt={alt} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Mapping the image would look like this:

```
<div>
    {arrayOfImages.map((el) => (
            <OnHoverImage
              alt={el.alt}
              hoveredImage={el.hoverImage}
              image={el.image}
            />
          ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are of course many ways to do this. One such way is by having a single state that represents all images:

```
const images = [...];

const Component = (props) => {
  const [imageStates, setImageStates] = useState({});

  const setImageHoveringState = (imageId, state) => {
    setImageStates({
      ...imageStates,
      imageId: state,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {images.map((image) => {
        // If the images don't have an ID, just use their index in the array
        return (
          <Card
            key={image.id}
            onMouseEnter={() => setImageHoveringState(image.id, true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setImageHoveringState(image.id, false)}
          />
            <IconWrapper>
              {imageStates[image.id] ? (
                <Image layout="fill" src={image2OnHover} />
              ) : (
                <Image layout="fill" src={image2} />
              )}
            </IconWrapper>
          </Card>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Either having a single state or different states is good. It depends on your preference. Actually different states is more definitive than the object state.

Object:

```
const [state, useState] = useState({ ... })
```

Different state

```
const [state1, useState] = useState()
const [state1, useState] = useState() 
const [state1, useState] = useState()
```

Another example, more clear

Having separate variables

```
    const num1 = 1
    const num2 = 2
    const num3 = 3
```

or having one object but different properties.

```
   const nums = {
    num1: 1,
    num2: 2,
    num3: 3
    }
```